Can a man wear a "women's watch"? Can a woman wear a "men's watch"?
Background
It's generally forbidden for a man to wear a woman's garment, or vice versa.  (Source.)
One type of wristwatch is the "men's watch".  Some are blue or black.  They're often bigger than women's watches.
Another type of wristwatch is the "women's watch".  Some are red or pink.  They're often smaller than men's watches.
Many watch companies, including Casio, Timex, Rolex, and others, market certain watches as "men's watches" or "women's watches" on their websites.
I don't know if watches are considered garments or not.  Especially if they're mostly plastic.  You see, plastic didn't even exist when the Shulchan Aruch was published.
Also, I know that a watch company might claim that a watch is a "men's watch" or a "women's watch".  But I don't if this has any halachic significance or not.
My questions

Is a man allowed to wear a women's watch?
Is a woman allowed to wear a men's watch?

Assume that each watch has a plastic case, a plastic strap, a metal caseback, and mixed materials inside.
If you cite sources, please preferably cite Modern Orthodox ones.  Thanks!
Possibly related

What are the opinions on men wearing a wrist watch? Is it considered beged isha?
Beged Isha/Ish when no intent to cross-dress.


We can see that Haredi women can even wear men's shirts, baseball hats, or sport shoes. I think the basic Halachic rule is that one should easily tell them apart from men (as Rashi says, they wouldn't mix). So the skirts and headwear suffice.

@AlBerko I don't think that is true. And I never heard of "men's" baseball hats, or seen a chareidi woman in a man's shirt.

@N.T. Why do we differentiate pants but not shirts or hats?

@AlBerko That's not relevant to the halacha. We either do or don't. And shirts are differentiated.

@AlBerko where do we see that?

Why should this be any different than any other garment?

@Dude:  Good comment!  I've edited my question.

I wear Garmin Fenix. As with many smartwatches, it comes in several sizes. Is a smaller watch necessarily "women's"? No. Your question is based on wrong semantics - there are no distinctively men's or women's features with watches. However, if there were, like men's are square and women's are round, that would be considered gender specific. To wit, there are many types of women's pants, and AFAIK they are still prohibited (despite being loved by many Religious Zionists).

@AlBerko:  I've edited the question.  ❧  If a watch is red or pink, might this halachically make it gender-specific?
